# jQuery e.target check only child and not parent element

Tags: jquery, cursor, mouse

I have a script that makes my mouse pretty:

```
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  jQuery('#cursor').eq(0).css({ left: e.clientX,top: e.clientY });
    if ( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' ){
        jQuery('#cursor').addClass('cursorLink');
    } else {
        jQuery('#cursor').removeClass('cursorLink');
    }
});
```

What this does, is whenever I hover over any element, it checks its tag. If the tag is `<a>` then it adds a classname on the cursor which gives the pretty style. When the element is not `<a>` then the class name is removed, returning back to the original cursor.

The problem I am dealing with, is that when my markup is like this:

`<a href="#"><img src="..." /></a>`

The JS code is returning the `<img>` tag instead of the `<a>` tag, which makes my mouse look normal instead of pretty.

Is it possible to check the parent element of every `e.target` and check if it's an `<a>` tag? Also, will this be heavy on computations? Will it have an impact on website performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  jQuery('#cursor').eq(0).css({ left: e.clientX,top: e.clientY });
        var get_tar = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        var get_par = e.target.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase();

        if ( (get_tar === 'a') || (get_par === 'a') || (get_tar === 'label') ){
            jQuery('#cursor').addClass('cursorLink');
        } else {
            jQuery('#cursor').removeClass('cursorLink');
        }

});
```

Fixed it! I simply made an `if` where i ask for the `e.target.parentNode.tagName` if it is an `<a>` element.